# Display date/time of deletion at /admin/recently-self-deleted

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, self-delete, recently-deleted

The "Recently Self-Deleted Posts" tool for diamond mods (/admin/recently-self-deleted) doesn't actually tell us *when* the posts in question were self-deleted - we have to click through to each individual post to find out when the deletion occurred. This is inconvenient. It would be nice if information about deletion date/time were included for each post on this page.